# Runtime error in Rat in a Maze Problem - I GFG

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, backtracking

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLysG.png)I am getting a runtime error for the rat in the maze problem. Could you pls tell me where I am going wrong?

**Problem:**

Consider a rat placed at (0, 0) in a square matrix of order N * N. It has to reach the destination at (N - 1, N - 1). Find all possible paths that the rat can take to reach from source to destination. The directions in which the rat can move are 'U'(up), 'D'(down), 'L' (left), and 'R' (right). Value 0 at a cell in the matrix represents that it is blocked and the rat cannot move to it while value 1 at a cell in the matrix represents that the rat can be travel through it.
Note: In a path, no cell can be visited more than one time. If the source cell is 0, the rat cannot move to any other cell.

**Code:**

```
class Solution:
    def findPath(self, m, n):
        # code here
        if m[0][0]==0 or m[n-1][n-1]==0:
            return []
        list_of_ans=[]
        vis=[]
        ans=''
        vis=[[0 for _ in range(n)]for _ in range(n)]
        list_of_ans=self.search(n,m,ans,0,0,list_of_ans,vis)
        list_of_ans.sort()
        return list_of_ans  
    
    def search(self,n,m,ans,i,j,list_of_ans,vis):
        if i==n-1 and j==n-1:
            list_of_ans.append(ans)
            return list_of_ans
    
        if vis[i][j+1]==0 and j+1<n and m[i][j+1]==1:
            vis[i][j+1]=1
            ans += 'R'
            list_of_ans=self.search(n,m,ans,i,j+1,list_of_ans,vis)
            vis[i][j+1]=0


        if vis[i-1][j]==0 and i-1>-1 and m[i-1][j]==1:
            vis[i-1][j]=1
            ans+='U'
            list_of_ans=self.search(n,m,ans,i-1,j,list_of_ans,vis)
            vis[i-1][j]=0


        if vis[i][j-1]==0 and j-1>-1 and m[i][j-1]==1:
            vis[i][j-1]=1
            ans+='L'
            list_of_ans=self.search(n,m,ans,i,j-1,list_of_ans,vis)
            vis[i][j-1]=0


        if vis[i+1][j]==0 and i+1<n and m[i+1][j]==1:
            vis[i+1][j]=1
            ans+='D'
            list_of_ans=self.search(n,m,ans,i+1,j,list_of_ans,vis)
            vis[i+1][j]=0
        return list_of_ans
```

**Input:**

```
N = 4
m[][] = {{1, 0, 0, 0},
         {1, 1, 0, 1}, 
         {1, 1, 0, 0},
         {0, 1, 1, 1}}
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/e06cd8a4132efe0b88133e02abde22fd.py", line 70, in <module>
    result = ob.findPath(matrix, n[0])
  File "/home/e06cd8a4132efe0b88133e02abde22fd.py", line 12, in findPath
    list_of_ans=self.search(n,m,ans,0,0,list_of_ans,vis)
  File "/home/e06cd8a4132efe0b88133e02abde22fd.py", line 47, in search
    list_of_ans=self.search(n,m,ans,i+1,j,list_of_ans,vis)
  File "/home/e06cd8a4132efe0b88133e02abde22fd.py", line 26, in search
    list_of_ans=self.s.................
```

Comment: "I am getting a runtime error for the rat in the maze problem" What is the error? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: That's a good start, but you cut it too short. You MUST show the ENTIRE error message. The important parts to solve this are left out from what you currently have.

Comment: This is actually the entire error message

Comment: Can you please point out what am I missing to solve this

Comment: Is this leetcode or some other code problem website? What you show as the error message isn't actually all of it. I suspect that whatever site you are using just truncates the error. Unfortunately, that means it hides the critical details you need in order to figure out what is wrong. Without the last line that says what the error actualy is, we can't help.

Comment: Do you know what the input is that causes this error? If not, you will have to try to come up with input based on the problem description to try and find something that causes your code to break.

Comment: For example, can `i` ever be `0`? If so, then `vis[i-1][j]` will throw an error. Similarly if `j` is ever too big `vis[i][j+1]` will cause an error. Try coming up with examples that cause those two cases to break.

Comment: It is GFG. Thank you I changed the if statements and it worked

Comment: What is GFG stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if vis[i][j+1]==0 and j+1<n and m[i][j+1]==1:
```

This might cause an error because it evaluates `vis[i][j+1]==0` before checking `j+1<n`. So if `j` ever equals `n`, the first check will cause an error before checking of `j+1` if valid.

To fix this, just change the order of your conditions. You need to make similar changes to all of your `if` statements.